# Get element on facebook page using php & curl

Tags: php, curl

I've tried this to get an html element from a public facebook event page in a file i named proxy.php:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html');
  $ch = curl_init('http://www.facebook.com/pages/Revive/137584936302228?sk=events');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

And using this ajax to get the content from it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-content/themes/revive/proxy.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    events = $('div#pagelet_events', data).html();
    // events = $('#text-5', data).html();
    $('#events-section').append(events);
  },
});
```

But that isn't working out for some reason. How I can I get this to work?

Thanks!

---

**Update:** So that got me closer but looking at the code that the proxy.php it's not just a div#pagelet_events that's loading on the page. Not sure if that makes sense. The only thing I can find referencing pagelet_events is this:

```
<script>big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":3,"id":"pagelet_events","is_last":true,"css":["AJXaB","3cT\/s"],"resource_map":{"AJXaB":{"type":"css","src":"http:\/\/f.static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yO\/r\/qjFDIQwXiny.css"}},"content":{"pagelet_events":"\u003cdiv class=\"UIImageBlock clearfix fbxNullState\">\u003cimg class=\"UIImageBlock_Image UIImageBlock_SMALL_Image img\" src=\"http:\/\/c.static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y9\/r\/56JC9tUWl0q.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" \/>\u003cdiv class=\"UIImageBlock_Content UIImageBlock_SMALL_Content\">\u003cp>You have no upcoming events.\u003c\/p>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>"},"tti_phase":3});</script>
```

Any idea if I can pull the content that this script is generating?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Facebook blocks any request if it comes from (or looks like its coming from) a script/bot. You need to add in a user-agent string to make it seem like it's a real request.

I modified your proxy script to this and it works (returns a result).

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html');
  $ch = curl_init('http://www.facebook.com/pages/Revive/137584936302228?sk=events');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
  echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```